# Почему возвращает undefined при попытке сделать request в nodejs?

Tags: node.js, google-maps-api

При попытке сделать request к api googlemaps возвращает undefined. Создал api ключ и хочу чтобы вернуло в формате json в консоле мой request.
С ключом и или без результат одинаковый у меня. Менял значения  `request.get` или `request.post` но все тоже самое.

Что не так делаю?

```
const request = require('request');
const url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&key=';
request({
  url: url,
  json: true
}, (error, response, body) => {
  console.log(body);
});
```

При смене значения в console.log() на error, выводит вот такую ошибку:

```
{ Error: tunneling socket could not be established, statusCode=302
    at ClientRequest.onConnect (C:\Users\Администратор\Desktop\Projects\weather-
app\node_modules\tunnel-agent\index.js:166:19)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:319:30)
    at emitThree (events.js:136:13)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:217:7)
    at Socket.socketOnData (_http_client.js:474:11)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:263:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:250:11)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:208:10) code: 'ECONNRESET' }
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "weather-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "request": "^2.87.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Ну так посмотрите что в `error` и `response`.

Comment: Вот [такое](https://prnt.sc/k7zy8g) выдало **error**

Comment: И какое отношение эта ошибка имеет к приведённому коду?

Comment: И вообще, тексты надо выкладывать текстом в вопросе, а не картинкой

Comment: Спасибо, отредактировал вопрос.

Comment: А в браузере эта ссылка у вас открывается?

Comment: Да, в формате json. [Вот](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&key=)

Comment: Откуда в ошибке какой-то tunnelling socket? Вы точно показываете нам тот код из-за которого возникает ошибка?  Ну и, формальный ответ на ваш вопрос: undefined потому что случилась ошибка.

Comment: А я откуда почему эта ошибка возникает?Весь код который использовал и ошибки с ним, я выложил уже.

Comment: Нет не весь. В вашем коде нет никакого упоминания про прокси, которым вы видимо пытаетесь воспользоваться.

Comment: Я не использую никакое прокси, только что выше сказал: node.js и текстовый редактор где установлен последняя версия пакета request. Добавил package.json в вопросе. Все равно спасибо что отвечаете.

Answer (score 0):

сделай так и будет тебе счастье.

```
const request = require('request')
const url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&key='

request(url, (err, res, body) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err)
    return
  } else {
    сonsole.log(res.body)
  }
})
```

Comment: Поменял код на ваш, но ошибка та же самая, что и выше.